# Regex issue with AngularJS ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation

I'm facing an issue with a regex using Angular JS ng-pattern.
I wrote the following regex for input validation that rejects all input containing newlines, tabs and carriage return:

```
\A(.*)[^\t\r\n]\z
```

I tested using Rubular and it works.
But then when I put in the ng-pattern of my .aspx the same expression with the 
bounds /myregex/ (that is: /\A(.*)[^\t\r\n]\z/ ) and, obviously I specify the trigger condition "...$error.pattern", it doesn't work, namely it always considers the input as wrong.
Edit: in my regex after "A(." there is also a *

Answer (score 1):

Javascript won't support `\A` (*start*), `\z` (*end*) anchors. So i suggest you to replace them with `^` and `$`

```
^(.*)[^\t\r\n]$
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use ^ and $ as my regex works also on multiple lines by checking for unwanted "newline" characters

Comment: so you want to match the lines which have no newline chars?

Comment: I want to match lines without newlines, tab and carriage return. I tested you suggestions but didn't work.

Comment: I finally solved it by using ^ and $ as start of string and end of string delimiters. So the final regex that works for Javascript is: ^(.*)[^\t\r\n]$

Comment: @OuterSpace thats what i said at first . See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28109026/revisions